# How do I solve a diffeential equation using a change of variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{1-x^2}+x$

I believe I should use the variable separation method, but I am having trouble separating x and y

Comment: Do you have to solve it using separation of variables or is any method OK? If so, are you familiar with integrating factors?

Comment: Could you give some context for this problem?  I do not think that this is easily solvable with separation of variables.

Comment: Your title mentions substitution while the question body wants separation. Which is it?

Comment: I think you cannot solve it by means of separation of variables. This is a linear equation, so you also have an explicit formula for it at your disposal. The formula is based on the method of integrated factors suggested by ekkilop

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For the DE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{x^2-1}y=x\tag{1}$$
an integrating factor is
\begin{align*}
\exp\left[\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx\right]&=\exp\left[\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right]\\
&=\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}